# How are simple effects calculated in JASP (and how to calculate them properly)?

Tags: r, anova, contrasts, jasp, simple-effects

I'm conducting **3-way (2x2x2) repeated measures ANOVA in JASP** with a main factor of interest called *symm*, and two other factors: *emotion* (neutral/fearful) and *masking* (masked/unmasked). **I want to resolve a significant 3-way interaction**. I assumed that I can do that either by looking at **contrasts** between levels of *symm* on different levels of *emotion* and *masking*, or by calculating **simple main effects** of *symm* including other factors as moderators. **However those two approaches gave me slightly different results (i.e. different p-values).**

Here is my JASP output: [image: ANOVA] [image]

When I did the same analysis in R I found that **contrasts in JASP gave the same results as `emmeans()` pairwaise contrasts, as well as `joint_tests()` function**, which is supposed to calculate simple main effects.

ANOVA:

```
rt_anova <- aov(rt~(emotion*masking*symm) + Error(subjects/(emotion*masking*symm)), data = rt_data)


>summary(rt_anova)
Error: subjects
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 40 6985050  174626               

Error: subjects:emotion
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
emotion    1    447     447   0.044  0.835
Residuals 40 406908   10173               

Error: subjects:masking
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
masking    1 188319  188319   13.46 0.000711 ***
Residuals 40 559675   13992                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subjects:symm
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)   
symm       1  29507   29507   10.07 0.0029 **
Residuals 40 117205    2930                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subjects:emotion:masking
                Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
emotion:masking  1 447140  447140   47.91 2.41e-08 ***
Residuals       40 373345    9334                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subjects:emotion:symm
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
emotion:symm  1  40357   40357   19.48 7.52e-05 ***
Residuals    40  82893    2072                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subjects:masking:symm
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
masking:symm  1   5275    5275   1.402  0.243
Residuals    40 150552    3764               

Error: subjects:emotion:masking:symm
                     Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
emotion:masking:symm  1  31182   31182   8.525 0.00573 **
Residuals            40 146309    3658                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Contrasts:

```
>emmeans(rt_anova, pairwise~symm|masking * emotion)$contrasts

masking = masked, emotion = fearful:
 contrast      estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 symm - unsymm    -8.26 12.3 153  -0.671  0.5030

masking = unmasked, emotion = fearful:
 contrast      estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 symm - unsymm    14.70 12.3 153   1.194  0.2344

masking = masked, emotion = neutral:
 contrast      estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 symm - unsymm   -13.63 12.3 153  -1.108  0.2698

masking = unmasked, emotion = neutral:
 contrast      estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 symm - unsymm   -68.68 12.3 153  -5.579  <.0001
```

Joint tests:

```
>joint_tests(rt_anova, by = c('masking', 'emotion'))

masking = masked, emotion = fearful:
 model term df1    df2 F.ratio p.value
 symm         1 152.73   0.451  0.5030

masking = unmasked, emotion = fearful:
 model term df1    df2 F.ratio p.value
 symm         1 152.73   1.425  0.2344

masking = masked, emotion = neutral:
 model term df1    df2 F.ratio p.value
 symm         1 152.73   1.227  0.2698

masking = unmasked, emotion = neutral:
 model term df1    df2 F.ratio p.value
 symm         1 152.73  31.129  <.0001
```

I also discovered that **simple main effects in JASP gave identical outcome as when I filtered the data into four subsets (each representing different combination of levels of *emotion* and *masking*) and conducted 1-way rm ANOVA of *symm* on each subset separately** - which obviously gives different results than marginal means analysis.

```
rt_data_m_f <- rt_data[rt_data$emotion == 'fearful' & rt_data$masking == 'masked',]
rt_data_m_n <- rt_data[rt_data$emotion == 'neutral' & rt_data$masking == 'masked',]
rt_data_u_f <- rt_data[rt_data$emotion == 'fearful' & rt_data$masking == 'unmasked',]
rt_data_u_n <- rt_data[rt_data$emotion == 'neutral' & rt_data$masking == 'unmasked',]

anova_m_f <- aov(rt~ symm +Error(subjects/symm), data = rt_data_m_f)
anova_m_n <- aov(rt~ symm +Error(subjects/symm), data = rt_data_m_n)
anova_u_f <- aov(rt~ symm +Error(subjects/symm), data = rt_data_u_f)
anova_u_n <- aov(rt~ symm +Error(subjects/symm), data = rt_data_u_n)


> summary(anova_m_f)

Error: subjects
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 40 2779065   69477               

Error: subjects:symm
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
symm       1   1400    1400   0.334  0.566
Residuals 40 167544    4189 
> summary(anova_m_n)

Error: subjects
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 40 1986706   49668               

Error: subjects:symm
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
symm       1   3810    3810    1.81  0.186              
> summary(anova_u_f)

Error: subjects
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 40 1825470   45637               

Error: subjects:symm
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
symm       1   4427    4427   2.434  0.127
Residuals 40  72756    1819                            
> summary(anova_u_n)

Error: subjects
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 40 1733736   43343               

Error: subjects:symm
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
symm       1  96685   96685   22.43 2.74e-05 ***
Residuals 40 172438    4311                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I also found [information](https://forum.cogsci.nl/discussion/6864/simple-main-effects-in-jasp-r-code), that simple main effects in JASP are based on emmeans package  which is additionally confusing.

I'm a bit lost here, especially that I have never seen the follow up analysis relying on separate ANOVAs on data subsets. Now I'm also wondering which method should I use on my data and why?

**Any comments are much appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that go into a test of a difference: the estimate, and its SE. Accordingly, ...

- Your model includes all interactions. For that reason, the estimated means from the model are just the means of each factor combination, thus you obtain the same estimated differences whether you use the one model or fit separate models. If your overall model had excluded any of the interactions, then your estimated differences would not necessarily be the same if you do separate models.
- The one model `rt_anova` uses *all of the errors* pooled together to derive an estimate of the SE of each difference of interest. However, the separate models `anova_m_f` ... `anova_u_n` each uses only *one fourth* of the errors to estimate its SEs. That yields different test statistics and different P values than you obtained from `rt_anova`.
- The P values obtained from `emmeans` and `joint_tests` for `rt_anova` are identical because those tests are exactly equivalent. By stat theory, if a random variable $T$ has a $t$ distribution with $d$ d.f., then $T^2$ has and $F$ distribution with $(1, d)$ d.f. Note in the output that each $F$ statistic from `joint_tests` is exactly equal to the square of the $t$ statistic from `emmeans`

I recommend *avoiding* doing separate ANOVAs in most cases, because fitting separate models mis-manages the errors. The exception would be cases where you have good reason to believe the population error variances are different between the cases. But if you are comfortable with an assumption that each case has the same error variance, you get better estimates and more powerful tests if you pool the errors together by fitting one model.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation, and all the tips! The same p-values for pairwise contrasts and joint_tests was exactly what I expected. I was just really surprised that JASP apparently conducts simple main effects as separate models. There is an option 'Pool error terms' when you specify simple main effects, but even when I checked it, p-values were still different from those provided by contrasts or emmeans package...

Comment: I don't know anything about JASP, but if it fits separate models to do simple effects, that is unconventional and a poor design choice in my opinion.

Comment: Please see 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/my-upvoting-policy, 
when you find a question sufficiently clear to 
write an answer, consider to upvote the question!